# Why does a mocked Class not enter a not mocked function?

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot, mockito

I have got a class:

```
@Component
public class GCInitializer
{
    @Autowired
    GCGoodRepository gcGoodRepository;

    @PostConstruct
    public void onStartup() throws Exception
    {
        // load/update base data
        initGCBaseData();
    }

    private void initGCBaseData() throws Exception 
    {
        ArrayList<GCGood> dbGoods;
        ArrayList<GCGood> fileGoods;
        ArrayList<GCGood> baseGoods;

        dbGoods = getGCGoodsFromDB();
        fileGoods = getGoodsFromFile();
        baseGoods = getGoodsFromInitializer();

        // do my merge magic
        […]
    }

    private ArrayList<GCGood> getGoodsFromInitializer() {
        ArrayList<GCGood> baseGoods = new ArrayList<>();
        […]
    }
    […]
}
```

This class searches three different Datasources at startup to get different Goods and to combine them without duplicates.

Now I want to write Unittests with Mockito:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class GCInitializerTest {

    @Autowired
    GCGoodRepository gcGoodRepository;

    @Test
    public void onStartupFirstTime() throws InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException 
    {
        // normal Start: after Start there are only 7 goods in it!!! (Db far away Off, File empty => only Standards!!!)
        GCInitializer gcInitializer = Mockito.mock(GCInitializer.class);
        Mockito.when(gcInitializer.getGoodsFromFile()).thenReturn(null);
        Mockito.when(gcInitializer.getGCGoodsFromDB()).thenReturn(null);
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(gcInitializer, "gcGoodRepository", gcGoodRepository);
        gcGoodRepository.deleteAll();

        // private invokation of GCInitializer::initGCBaseData()
        Method method = GCInitializer.class.getDeclaredMethod("initGCBaseData");
        method.setAccessible(true);
        method.invoke(gcInitializer);

        assertEquals(Lists.newArrayList(gcGodRepository.findAll()).size(), 7);
    }
    [...]
}
```

Runnig with debugger the function GCInitializer::getGoodsFromInitializer() is never entered and returns null, instead of an Array with 7 GCGoods.

Why is that so? How can I achieve that this function gives me the right ArrayList back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do agree with memo, but still if you want to do It you can use real partial mocks https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.20.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#16 for example:

```
when(mock.someMethod()).thenCallRealMethod();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a mock, so it doesn't have the real methods implemented. You might want to use a spy instead.